# COINS on SPOJ — Every time getting a runtime error (SIGSGEV)

Tags: c

/***********************************************************************************************************************************COINS problem on SPOJ."http://www.spoj.com/problems/COINS/".Every time I'm getting a runtime error (SIGSGEV). Please help with what's wrong. It runs well on my machine and I can't find any problem. It gives correct output as well. But in SPOJ it is not getting accepted.
***********************************************************************************************************************************/

```
#include<stdio.h>

long long  arr[1000000]; /* Is this large number ok?*/

long long coins(long long n)/*Used recursion*/
{
    if(n==0)
        return 0;

    if(arr[n]!=0)
        return arr[n];

    long long a,b,c,sum;
    a=n/2;
    b=n/3;
    c=n/4;
    sum=coins(a)+coins(b)+coins(c);
    if(sum>n)
    {
        arr[n]=sum; /*Dynamic programming*/
        return sum;
    }
    else
    {
        arr[n]=n;   /*Dynamic programming*/
        return n;
    }
}

int main()
{
    long long n;
    while(scanf("%lld",&n))//Have doubt in this. Should it be while(scanf(...)!=EOF)
    {
    long long dollar=coins(n);
    printf("%lld\n",dollar);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There should be a problem link, right ?

Comment: you problem is with array arr[] :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  If you want help with a problem, you need to identify what the program is supposed to do, with sample inputs and expected and actual outputs. Remember that the SPOJ projects usually give you information about the size of the inputs.  It is not obvious why you'd need one million long long integers, but I've not gone to find the question — you should provide us with a link to the question.  It is very likely that your problem is the size of that array; it is pretty darn big.

Comment: Perhaps if you told people what "COINS problem on SPOJ" meant, they could help you.

Comment: does it crash for every input? or only for large ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem show that n <= 1000000000, and in function coins, you will use arr[n], which will absolutely be out of the range of 1000000.

But I think you are on the right way~

A hint: consider 2^32 > 1000000000, so how many sub-problems?

Comment: Sorry, but didnot get the hint.